# Framework7 (Dom7): JSONP

Tags: jsonp, html-framework-7

I am using [Fremework7 v1.4.0](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/dom.html) and there is no `jsonpCallback` or `jsonp` and other related JSONP parameters in the documentation. Only `crossDomain: true` is available out there.

Is Framework7 (Dom7) supports **JSONP** and callback parameters like jQuery?

I've used the code below without success:

```
var $$ = Dom7;
$$.ajax({
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
    contentType: "OPTIONS",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
        q: "select title,abstract,url from search.news where query=\"cat\"",
        format: "json"
    },
    success: function( response ) {
        alert( 'ok' );
        alert( response );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know this way is the best way or not, I had the same problem and this way works for me.

```
var $$ = Dom7;
$$.ajax({
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
    contentType: "OPTIONS",
    dataType : 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
        q: "select title,abstract,url from search.news where query=\"cat\"",
        format: "json",
        callback:function(){
           return true;
        }
    },
    success: function( response ) {
        alert( 'ok' );
        alert( response );
    }
});
```